# Fetching data from parse to Table View Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to fetch data from parse and present it in a table view. I'm not able to compile the code as there's an error.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class EventsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Array to store event timeline objects from parse
    var eventtimelineData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.loadData()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func loadData(){

        // first remove the contents from the array
        eventtimelineData.removeAllObjects()

        var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")

        findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
             (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            // if query doesn't return any error
            if !error{
                for object:PFObject! in objects{
                    self.timelineData.addObject(object)
                }

                let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray

                self.tableView.reloadData()


            }

        }
    }
```

This is the error that am getting:

> ([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void' is not convertible to 'PFArrayResultBlock?

Could you please help me figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: I believe NSError! should be NSError?. If you wanted, you could just write objects,error instead of objects : [AnyObject]!,error : NSError!

Comment: try like this (results: [AnyObject], error: NSError) -> Void in

Comment: Thanks Josh, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Parse updated their query syntax. This works.

```html
@IBAction func loadData(){

        // first remove the contents from the array
        eventtimelineData.removeAllObjects()


        let query = PFQuery(className:"Events")
        query.whereKey("CreatedBy", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {

                        self.eventtimelineData.addObject(object)
                        print(object.objectId)
                        print(object.description)
                    }

                    let array:NSArray = self.eventtimelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                    self.eventtimelineData = array.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }


            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Done")
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }

    }
```